# Error por excepción al crear mi servidor vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Hola estoy intentando hacer un simple servidor en vb.net bueno lo hice pero esque ahora me da una excepción. La excepción es la siguiente:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An attempt was made to
access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress
socketAddress)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(EndPoint localEP)
   at System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener.Start(Int32 backlog)
   at System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener.Start()
   at name.TCPControl..ctor() in C:\Users\never\Desktop\New folder\TCPServerClea
n\name\TCPControl.vb:line 23
   at name.Program.Main() in C:\Users\never\Desktop\New folder\TCPServerClean\na
me\Program.vb:line 12
```

El código de mi servidor:

```vb
Module Program
    Public Server As TCPControl 
    Sub Main()
        Server = New TCPControl
        Console.Write("Press any key to continue . . . ")
        Console.ReadKey(True)
    End Sub
End Module
```

Código de mi clase TCP:

```vb
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.Threading

Public Class TCPControl
    Public Event MessageReceived(sender As TCPControl, Data As String)

    ' SERVER CONFIG
    Public ServerIP As IPAddress = IPAddress.Any
    Public ServerPort As Integer = 64555
    Public Server As TcpListener

    Private CommThread As Thread
    Public IsListening As Boolean = True

    ' CLIENTS
    Private Client As TcpClient
    Private ClientData As StreamReader

    Public Sub New()
        Server = New TcpListener(ServerIP, ServerPort)
        Server.Start()

        CommThread = New Thread(New ThreadStart(AddressOf Listening))
        CommThread.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Listening()
        ' CREATE LISTENER LOOP
        Do Until IsListening = False
            ' ACCEPT INCOMING CONNECTIONS
            If Server.Pending = True Then
                Client = Server.AcceptTcpClient
                ClientData = New StreamReader(Client.GetStream)

            End If

            ' RAISE EVENT FOR INCOMING MESSAGES
            Try
                RaiseEvent MessageReceived(Me, ClientData.ReadLine)
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try

            ' REDUCE CPU USAGE
            'Thread.Sleep(100)
        Loop
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: ¿Seguro no tienes un proceso que ya está ocupando el port 64555? Si pruebas con un número diferente, que pasa?

Comment: y si pruebas con `IPAddress.Loopback` en vez de `IPAddress.Any`, ¿cambia algo?

Comment: parece que los puertos que cojo siempre estan ocupados como el 64555 , es mejor probar con otros más comunes

Comment: @Perl no entiendo si ya lo solucionaste usando otro puerto o si se sigue disparando el error. ¿Podrías aclararlo? ¿Qué pruebas hiciste? ¿Eran sobre un puerto que estaba libre?

Comment: probe otro puerto el 92 funciona parece ser que ese siempre esta cogido no se porque